# The issue with separately compiling the data package and meta package of the CnosDB package?

Tags: cnosdb

So here's the thing, I'm using the docker/Docker file in the source code to compile the data package separately, but I found that meta and tskv are also included in the compilation list. Can you tell me why this is happening? Do they have mutual dependencies?

The compilation process is as follows:

```
   Compiling datafusion v22.0.0 (https://github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git?branch=22.0.0#2b432d13)
   Compiling datafusion-proto v22.0.0 (https://github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git?branch=22.0.0#2b432d13)
   Compiling memory_pool v2.3.1 (/cnosdb/common/memory_pool)
   Compiling models v2.3.1 (/cnosdb/common/models)
   Compiling http_protocol v2.3.1 (/cnosdb/common/http_protocol)
   Compiling meta v2.3.1 (/cnosdb/meta)
   Compiling tskv v2.3.1 (/cnosdb/tskv)
   Compiling protocol_parser v2.3.1 (/cnosdb/common/protocol_parser)
```

Moreover, the individually packaged data file also encountered an error, with the following error message:

```
    The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: MetaClientErr { msg: "NetworkError: reqwest::error::Error: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8901/read): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111) source: error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111) source: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111) source: Connection refused (os error 111)" }
Location: /cnosdb/meta/src/model/meta_admin.rs:98

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 9 frames hidden ⋮
  10: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::create_meta::{{closure}}::hf1c6328264c26c69
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  11: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}::h125d736bba73065f
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}::hdf5b5354f807b594
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: cnosdb::main::h42cec1a2c44d1de9
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::he86a9c8706793327
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  15: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::hd3ce7cc7b8747ae3
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  16: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::h5e81a211ebe2032f
      at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287
  17: std::panicking::try::do_call::h126a1666e80cc20e
      at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487
  18: std::panicking::try::hfb5ede04440ec459
      at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451
```

What is the issue/problem, may I ask?